# Service Class representation in UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have three classes one is called

`WorkCoordinator` and it calls different service classes depending on an event passed to it, so if the event is `trackIssue` there is a `TrackService` class that handles some operations specifically for tracking and there is also a `Track` object. So  you could have the following

`WorkCoordinator  -- (track issue) --> TrackService  (has a list of Track objects)`

How would you correctly represent these three in a UML diagram ? where everything starts with the workcoordinator which uses a `TrackService` and `TrackService` may have a function like add(Track track), where you would pass it a Track object to add to an array list within it say:

`private ArrayList<Track> tracks;`

and as add gets called, then a track is added to tracks.

Appreciate any insights, I was thinking something like this but may be totally wrong.

[image]

Comment: Except for duplicating attribute `trackItems` with the role `tracks` I see no issues. The shared aggregation is superfluous. Likewise the association label _Relation_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have three classes one is called

Contrarily to an operation a class cannot be *called*, but it can be *used*.

> `WorkCoordinator  -- (track issue) --> TrackService`

when the event string is *trackIssue* the class *WorkCoordinator* uses the class *TrackingService*, but how ? Because in your diagram the class *TrackingService* only has the operation *add* that means that operation is called, even I have some doubt about that, more the fact we don't know from where the instance of *Track* given in argument comes from. If an other operation is called add it in the diagram.

About your diagram :

- the role of the line between *WorkCoordinator* and *TrackingService* is unknown as it is, and then invalid. Because of the attribute *trackingService* probably you wanted to also show it as a relation, in that case the relation must completed.
- *TrackingService* has two lists of *Track*, one though the attribute *trackItems* and an other one through the relation *tracks*. This is probably not what you wanted, and *trackItems* must be renamed *tracks* or the reverse.
- to show the same thing through an attribute and a relation is legal in UML, but quite heavy because the reader must check they are the same thing, I encourage you to use only one of them, and to favor the relation when both classes are drawn.
- your aggregation says *TrackingService* is composed of *Track*, are you sure this is the case and an aggregation must be used ?

> How would you correctly represent these three in a UML diagram ?

The class diagram does not indicate at all that when the processed event is *trackIssue* the operation *add* (or an other) is applied on *trackingService* (with the right argument). Of course you can add a note to say that, but that note is a free text and only human can understand it.

To show that in a diagram you can use a sequence diagram or an activity diagram, depending on what you want to show.

The sequence diagram showing what happens during the execution of *process* can be (supposing a new instance of *Track* is created to be given in argument to *add*) :

[image]

*event* is supposed to be the argument of *process*, to name the instance of *TrackingService* I used *trackingService* being the name of the attribute, and *item* represents the created instance of *Track* to use it in the message *add*.

All of that seems vague, but this is normal because an interaction is not a behavior, and a sequence diagram focuses on message interchange between lifelines.

If you want to fully model the behavior of the operation *process* without ambiguity you can use an activity, and the diagram can be :

[image]

---

Additional remarks :

- An event is generally much more than a name like *trackIssue*, so the parameter of *process* is not a string or that string is a complex form.
- *Track* has *getter/setter* for the *id* but not for the *name*, seems strange. Are you sure the *id* is not only set (with *name*) when an instance is created ?

Comment: Sorry when i said called i meant "its named"  thanks for the feedback

Comment: Yes what I posted above is a vague idea of what i was trying to accomplish and your remark help me to improve on this. really appreciated.